# Node.js Server and Cognito Sync

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a Node.js Server which will pickup data from a local DB and put it to Cognito. I cannot use CognitoSyncManager because this is not a browser app.
Can anyone tell me how can I upload the data? 
Also, I am unable to find out how to create dataset and how to upload data to dataset using CognitoSync.
Sorry, I am a newbee to Cognito that is why asking such a basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Cognito Sync with AWS Node Js SDK, you will need to use the class CognitoSync instead of CognitoSyncManager. Here's the API reference
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoSync.html

Following blog has a good guide on getting started with Cognito Sync with Node Js
https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1KD3G8Q9NFWVF/Amazon-Cognito-in-your-Node-js-web-app

Comment: No, I do not have restriction of using CognitoSync, I just wanted a suggestion about how to go for it.